# Column slicer in Power BI report?

Tags: reporting, powerbi, dax, powerbi-datasource

I have a requirement to cook my report with local languages. I have three description columns in my table and need to show one at a time based on user input.

Example:

```
CustName | Product | English_Description | Swedish_Description
```

My table has 5 millions of records, so i can't go for un-pivot the description columns. if I do un-pivot, my table becomes 10 millions of records. it's not a feasible one.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample data would be useful. However, you could do a disconnected (or parameter) table for the language selection:

```
Language
--------
English
Swedish
```

This table wouldn't be related to anything else, but you could then use measures for your product descriptions such as:

```
Multi-lingual Description =
IF (
    'Disconnected Table'[Language] = "Swedish",
    MAX ( [Swedish_Description] ),
    MAX ( [English_Description] )
)
```

With this logic, if no language is picked, the English description will be used. You could use different behavior too (for example use HASONEVALUE to ensure a single value is selected, and display an error message if not).

MAX in the measure is because a measure has to aggregate; however, as long as your table has one product for each row, then the MAX of the product name will be the product name you expect. Having more than one product per row doesn't make sense, so this should be an acceptable limitation. Again, to make your measure more robust, you could build in logic using HASONEVALUE to show BLANK() or an error message if there is more than one product (e.g. for subtotals).

More information:

HASONEVALUE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492190.aspx

Disconnected Tables: http://www.daxpatterns.com/parameter-table/